# How to automatically sign into Google OAuth for a single owner of Google Blogger account

Tags: javascript, ajax, oauth, google-oauth, blogger

I am trying to take the most recent posts from my google blogger account and integrate them into my website. Lately I've been playing around with Google OAuth to get the access token to retrieve my posts with ajax requests. However in order to get the access token I had to open a window to google and manually sign in every time.

Is there a way to have my site automatically sign into google given my credentials, get the access token and make an ajax request to get the most recent posts from my blogger account?

Also is this possible with only javascript?

I want to be able to display some of my blogger posts on my website without having display google's blogger page.

Comment: If you can't find a way, this may hep to make it more dynamic: https://developers.google.com/+/web/embedded-post/#gapi.post.render